# Facebook Like on site displays incorrectly as flag icon on timeline

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I have a like button on a page that includes all open graph tags required and which is validated by the Facebook debugger. See the debugger results here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fclasstivity.com%2Fiyengar-yoga-institute-nyc

When pressing like on the site, the page is displayed in the Facebook timeline as:
- no image, just the icon of a flag
- in the like box with likes for Facebook pages (which is separate from the like box module with pages liked on other websites)

The page requires regular visiting users to sign in but the Facebook user agent is allowed to see the page, thus the successful result from the Facebook debugger (link above).

The like button is used is the iframe one. Entering the URL for the page in the page where you generate a like button and hitting like there produces the same results however.

Has anyone experienced this issue and/or know a solution?